# express.js The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to make an auth with sending token via cookies and Authorization header to ensure that username from header and username from decoded token are identical. But the problem is, when I send authorization header, on backend OPTIONS request fails with 204 error. Without header it works perfectly. 
What I've tried: 
Added middleware for handling this, OPTIONS still 204.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`headers`)
  console.log(req.headers)
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With")
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization")
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS")
  if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
    res.send(200)
  }
  else {
    next();
  }
})
```

2. Set up cors

`app.use(cors({withCredentials: true, credentials: true, origins: 'http://localhost:8080'}))`

3. Set up socket.io

   ```
   var socket = require('socket.io')
   var app = express(),
   var http = require('http').createServer(app)
   const io = new socket(http, { path: '/api/chat', origins: 'http://localhost:8080' })
   http.listen(3000, () => console.log(`App is running on localhost:3000`.bold.yellow))
   const events = require('./src/socket')(io);
   ```

But it still doesnt work. What could have I missed?

Comment: Forgot to mention, the frontend is on :8080 port and I'm accessing server on :3000.

Comment: Do you have 1 **and** 2 in your code? So you have two separate middleware things both trying to add CORS headers?

Comment: Apparently, yes. I removed 1, but it still doesnt work.